# java api to read certificate and CRL from same pem file

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have my certificate and CRL in same PEM file as below

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----

-----END X509 CRL-----

I am trying to read the data as below

```
 try
  { 
    ByteArrayInputStream temp= new ByteArrayInputStream( cacert_file_data );

        while(temp.available()>0 )
        {
            x509_cacert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(temp);

            if (x509_cacert == null) { return ; }   // paranoid

            cert_list.add( x509_cacert );
        }

    }
    catch (CertificateException e)
    {some code}
```

In case of CRL it throws CertificateException , is there way I can avoid this exception and read CRL gracefully, without exception from same file.

Comment: **Certificates and CRLs are different things.** `generateCertificate` handles a certificate and only a certificate, not a CRL, and `generateCertificates` or `generateCertPath` handles certificates (plural) but not CRL(s). `generateCRL` handles a CRL, and `generateCRLs` handles CRLs (plural). For the CRL **use `generateCRL`** or possibly `generateCRLs` and not `generateCertificate[s]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bis= new ByteArrayInputStream( cacert_file_data );
    int count = bis.available();
    int pos = 0;
    String cacert_str;

    try
    {
        while(bis.available()>0 )
        {

            x509_cacert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bis);

            if (x509_cacert == null) { return ; }   // paranoid

            cert_list.add( x509_cacert );
            pos = count - bis.available();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read(bytes, 0, bis.available());
            bis.reset();
            bis.skip(pos);
            cacert_str = new String( bytes );
            if(!cacert_str.contains("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"))
            {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
```